# socket.io Websocket connection inside a HTML5 SharedWorker

Tags: websocket, socket.io, web-worker

I hope you all are doing well. I'm trying to establish connection to **socket.io** server from inside of the **worker.js** file using **importScripts** which loads the [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) js file which is in the same directory with worker.js. After loading socket.io-client 
by using var socket = io.connect('http://38.98.xxx.xxx:6000'); I am trying to establish connection to socket.io server on different host, but it ain't working. Please point me in the right direction.I appreciate any help.

```
    <script>
    var worker = new SharedWorker("http://baseUrl.com/js/push/worker/worker.js");

    worker.port.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        console.log("Got message: " + e.data);
    }, false);
    worker.port.start();
    worker.port.postMessage("start");

</script>
```

**worker.js**

```
importScripts('socket.io.js');

var socket = io.connect('http://38.98.154.167:6000');

var connections = 0;

self.addEventListener("connect", function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    connections ++;
    port.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        if (e.data === "start") {

            port.postMessage('hello');
        }
    }, false);
    port.start();
}, false);


socket.on('connect', function () {
    port.postMessage('connect');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    port.postMessage('disconnect');
});
```

Comment: I'm not certain (this is why it's a comment, not an answer), but I'm pretty sure that websockets in a shared-worker aren't implemented for all browsers. Last I checked, Firefox had major issues with this... but good luck!

Comment: Hi! Myst, thanks for the comment. I'm planning to use it with Chrome only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out. Just had to move

```
socket.on('connect', function () {
    port.postMessage('connect');
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    port.postMessage('disconnect');
});
```

into the `self.addEventListener("connect", function(e) {});`in the `worker.js` and change from `var socket=io.connect('http://38.98.xxx.xxx:6000');`
to

```
var socket = io('http://38.98.xxx.xxx:6000');
```

Here is the working example is case if anybody needs.

**worker.js**

```
  importScripts('socket.io.js');

var socket = io('http://38.98.xxx.xxx:6000');

var connections = 0;

self.addEventListener("connect", function(e) {
    var port = e.ports[0];
    connections ++;
    port.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        if (e.data === "start") {

            port.postMessage('hello');
        }
    }, false);
    port.start();

    socket.on('push', function(pushed){

        port.postMessage(pushed);
    });


    socket.on('connect', function () {
        port.postMessage('connect');
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        port.postMessage('disconnect');
    });

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a drop in replacement for `const io = require('socket.io-client');`

which runs the connection for the returned socket in a dedicated webworker. It is

```
const io = require('sockerworker.io');
const socket = io([url][, options]);
```

Instead of writing your own boilerplate for the webworker, you could use this. It is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketworker.io) via npm. (disclosure: I am its author.)